# untermitated string literal when using resources in razor

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a razor code which is using resorces from resources.resx. When i use it in a function (java script), it shows error as "unterminated string literal". How do I use resources in my java script code? However in html part of my code it is able to get the actual value if @mynamespace.name

```
function check(arg)
{
...
var name = "@mynamespace.name";
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use Razor in javascript file, because javascript files are static. All you can do is use `script` section in your `.cshtml` file. You can make a walk-around following jcreamer898 post https://stackoverflow.com/a/9406739/4563955

```
// someFile.js
var myFunction = function(options){
    // do stuff with options
};

// razorFile.cshtml
<script>
    window.myFunction = new myFunction(@model.Stuff);
    // If you need a whole model serialized then use...
    window.myFunction = new myFunction(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(model)));
</script>
```