# Insert C# method to Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, razor, model-view-controller

I've got a method that translates string according to selected language on the webpage, I'm using it to wrap all the strings on html, but I've also got some javascript code that's rendering some html such as in example below, what i need to do is to somehow insert this wrapper method from c# to Javascript. Any ideas  on how can i achieve this?

html example:

```
<div>@Lang("String")</div>
```

Javascript:

```
 $(".highchart-tooltip-events").html("<div><strong>Events:</strong></div>" + $evtsList.html());  now this Events string should be passed to the translate method.
```

Comment: You can't run c# in JavaScript, you can only do an AJAX request to the server to do the translation for you, or rewrite the function in Javascript.

Comment: I hoped there was a way around it, but okay. Thank you.

Comment: Take a peek here, its pretty much the same question you ask, you can get a wider view of your options here   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9406648/how-to-embed-razor-c-sharp-code-in-a-js-file