# ASP .NET Core how to generate razor Urls in javascript files?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core

I have a lot of javascript functions that i want to separate by logic into multiple javascript files. The problem is that all my ajax functions urls are generated by razor.

```
 $.get('@Url.Page("Index","ViewReferenceRecordsPartial")', { productionRecordId: productionRecordId }, function (response) {

        $('#details').html(response)
        stopLoading(element);
    })
```

How can i keep my function like this on a js file?

**UPDATE**

Here is a temporary solution until there is a more maintainable solution which is pretty quick to do using data attributes.

in a js file i have this function

```
function viewReferenceRecords(element, productionRecordId) {
    startLoading(element);
    $.get($(element).data('url'), { productionRecordId: productionRecordId }, function (response) {

        $('#details').html(response)

        stopLoading(element);
    })
}
```

on my table I have a button that calls this function

```
<button data-url="@Url.Page("Index","ViewReferenceRecordsPartial")" onclick="viewReferenceRecords(this, @Model.Id)">Details</button>
```

it's very simple and easy, just store the Url generated by razor on a data attribute on the element and pass it to the function in the js file and retrieve the string generated on the data attribute.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to embed Razor C# code in a .js file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9406648/how-to-embed-razor-c-sharp-code-in-a-js-file)

Comment: This is the first solution i saw, i was trying to see if i could find another way

Answer (score 0):

I typically use the revealing module pattern for things like this. You can read about it here: https://gist.github.com/zcaceres/bb0eec99c02dda6aac0e041d0d4d7bf2

It's sort of like namespacing, but in JavaScript. Then you can pass in parameters. I would do it like this:

**JS file**

```js
var MeaningfulModuleName = MeaningfulModuleName || (function () {
    var _partialUrl = null;
    return {
        init: function (partialUrl) { _partialUrl = partialUrl; },
        loadPartial: function (targetSelector, productionRecordId) {
            $.get(_partialUrl, { productionRecordId: productionRecordId }, function (response) {
                $(targetSelector).html(response);
                // ...
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Then in your razor view, you create a script tag at the bottom of the page with this:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(() = {
        MeaningfulModuleName.init(@'Url.Page("Index", "ViewReferenceRecordsPartial")');

        // Some event occurs
        MeaningfulModuleName.loadPartial('#details', productionRecordId);
    }
</script>
```

Where `MeaningfulModuleName` is whatever name makes sense to you for this particular JS file.

This solves it for me, and I think it makes the JS look a bit cleaner, too. Everything is organized into "modules". Also, I apologize if the code doesn't work perfectly. I wrote this on my phone. :)

Comment: it gives me exception that MeaningfulModuleName is not defined on the js file

Comment: I updated my answer to include `var` on the first line of the JS file.

Comment: still couldn't manage to get this working, on the actual page says MeaningfulModuleName.init is not a function. For the time being i went with the data attributes  approach cause it's quick and works

Comment: @Jackal Could you share your solution which uses data attributes as an anwser?